# How to access column after pandas .groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that I used the .groupby() along with .agg() function on.

`movieProperties = combined_df.groupby(['movieId', 'title', 'genres']).agg({'rating': ['count', 'mean']})`

This is the code to create the new data frame. However I can't seem to access columns the same way anymore. If I try `movieProperties['genres']` I always get a KeyError. How can I access columns again in this new data frame?

Comment: You can't access the group like that. You ahve to do for example `movieProperties['crime']` or `movieProperties['drama']` . However, the way you have done the group, each movie will be a separate group because no two movies will have same `ID`s are 'Titles'

Comment: `groupby([...], as_index=False)` will make the grouped columns normal columns, else they are indexes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after you groupby, the columns you grouped by are now called `index`:

```
movieProperties = pd.DataFrame({"movie": ["x", "x", "y"], "title":["tx", "tx", "ty"], "rating": [3, 4, 3]}).groupby(["movie", "title"]).agg({"rating":["count", "mean"]})
movieProperties.index.values
Out[13]: array([('x', 'tx'), ('y', 'ty')], dtype=object)
```

if you're not comfortable with that, reset them back to regular columns:

```
movieProperties.reset_index()
Out[16]: 
  movie title rating     
               count mean
0     x    tx      2  3.5
1     y    ty      1  3.0
```

and then

```
movieProperties.reset_index()["movie"]
Out[17]: 
0    x
1    y
```